# cant figure out echo text if session auth=1 else echo text2

Tags: php, mysql, echo, if-statement

this is my first time working with sessions, im working on a members area, which i have managed to make but i need some users (admins) to be able to see some links that normal users cant. this is what i have sofar :s

```
   <?php
require_once('auth.php');
    ?>
    <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' id='memberstitle'>
    <tr>
        <td background='images/box2_l.png' width='20' height='50'></td>
        <td background='images/box2_m.png' height='50'>Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'];?>
            <table border='0' cellpadding='2' cellspacing='0' id='newsavatar'>
            <?php

        if(!isset($_SESSION['SESS_AUTH'] == '1') {
    echo '<tr>
                <td><a href='?p=post'>Post News</a> | <a href="">Post Screenshot</a> | <a href="">View Player List</a></td>
                <td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align:middle' width='34' height='34'><img src='images/<?php echo $_SESSION['SESS_AVATAR'];?>'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="?p=logout">Logout</a> | <a href="">Change Password</a> | <a href="">Change Avatar</a></td>
            </tr>';
            }
            else {
            echo'<tr>
                <td>Control Panel</td>
                <td rowspan='2' style='vertical-align:middle' width='34' height='34'><img src='images/<?php echo $_SESSION['SESS_AVATAR'];?>'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="?p=logout">Logout</a> | <a href="">Change Password</a> | <a href="">Change Avatar</a></td>
            </tr>';
            }

        ?>
        </table>

        </td>
        <td background='images/box2_r.png' width='20' height='50'></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: ...and what is happening? Without reading PHP manuals etc, I'd say !isset($_SESSION['SESS_AUTH'] == '1') is the culprit. Why == '1' inside the args list?

Comment: nothing is being shown, the =='1' is there to denote which members are admin 1=admin 0=non admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you start the session on the beginning of the file?

But even if you did, there are couple more errors in your code:

The `if` should be more like that:

```
    if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_AUTH']) && $_SESSION['SESS_AUTH'] == '1') {
```

And your 'echo' syntax is quite wrong as well:

- If you use ' to start the text you want to be written, you cannot use
  it in that text without an escape character. So you html attributes
  values should be `\'value\'` or `"value"`, instead of simple
  `'value'`.
- You cannot use `<?php  ?>` inside echo. Try string concatenation instead.

For example:

```
echo '<tr>
            <td><a href="?p=post">Post News</a> | <a href="">Post Screenshot</a> | <a href="">View Player List</a></td>
            <td rowspan="2" style="vertical-align:middle" width="34" height="34"><img src="images/' + $_SESSION['SESS_AVATAR'] + '"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="?p=logout">Logout</a> | <a href="">Change Password</a> | <a href="">Change Avatar</a></td>
        </tr>';
```

Comment: doing all that it now shows "Welcome firstname" and then a few lines down "0" nothing else

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use `$ _SESSION` you need to start the session with `session_start()`. You have done it at some point? After that, check what you have inside the `$_SESSION` variable with `var_dump`:

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Comment: array
  'SESS_MEMBER_ID' => string '2' (length=1)
  'SESS_FIRST_NAME' => string 'firstname' (length=9)
  'SESS_LAST_NAME' => string 'lastname' (length=8)
  'SESS_AVATAR' => string 'tb.png' (length=6)
  'SESS_AUTH' => string '1' (length=1)